# Merit Gem: expiring points

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, merit-gem

I'm giving discounts on products based on user's point total. But I would like to encourage users to use those points within 180 days. So, only points created_at < 180.days.ago would count.

What would be a simple way to get the only punctuation from 180 days ago?

Comment: does the act of awarding points generate an instance of something recording how many points were added and when in your database?

Comment: I'm using this gem: https://github.com/tute/merit . I think it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems too late but now I'm working on similar situation and I find this example in their own documents.

https://github.com/tute/merit#other-actions-1

In your case code would be something like this.

```
user.score_points.where("created_at > '#{180.days.ago}'").sum(:num_points)
```

Apparently, `#points` returns mere integer (not a Point object). So if you wanted to pick and choose points with their given date, you need to use `#score_points` instead.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Merit, so you'll have to look at what models it gives you, but you can probably do something like this in your user model:

```
class User < ActiveModel::Base
  def validPonts
    self.points.select{ |p| p.created_at > 180.days.ago } 
  end
end
```

and then you call @user.validPoints to retrieve only the points that exist from the last 180 days.